# Android's SQLite, how to turn Cursors into strings?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Say I have such helper:

```
public class SqlHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SqlHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, PLACE TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable (NAME, PLACE) VALUES('ANTHONY','USA')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable (NAME, PLACE) VALUES('BERIMOR','UK')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable (NAME, PLACE) VALUES('IVAN','RUSSIA')");
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


}
```

and in my main code I execute a query

```
    SqlHelper sqlHelper = new SqlHelper(this, "MyDataBase.db", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase DB = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = DB.query(
            "MyTable" /* table */,
            new String[] { "PLACE" } /* columns */,
            "id = ?" /* where or selection */,
            new String[] { "RUSSIA" } /* selectionArgs */,
            null /* groupBy */,
            null /* having */,
            null /* orderBy */
        );

    DB.close();
```

But I'm not sure what that cursor thing is? Shouldn't it be something like an array? And if so, how do I get original values ( strings ) out of it? Like this query should return 'IVAN'.

Thanks!

EDIT2 :

This ( c.getCount() ) still returns 0, i.e. no results... hmm... maybe then there's something with the helper?

```
     Cursor c = DB.query(
                "MyTable" /* table */,
                new String[] { "NAME" } /* columns */,
                "PLACE = 'RUSSIA'" /* where or selection */,
                null /* selectionArgs */,
                null /* groupBy */,
                null /* having */,
                null /* orderBy */
            );



    Log.e("DB RETURNS", String.valueOf( c.getCount() ) );
```

Comment: See my edited answer. You query is incorrect.

Comment: tied that too, still 0! So guess it's something with the helper?

Comment: I'm not an android developer by any stretch, so I'd be guessing here. Try redefining your id field as an android id field. "CREATE TABLE MyTable (" + android.provider.BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"

Answer (score 2):

A cursor is a pointer to the results set of your query.  Read the Cursor documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Basically, you'll do something like:

```
String place;
if (c.moveToFirst){
    place = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("PLACE"));
}
```

Comment: hmm, throws an error. Obviously because c.getCount() returns a 0, i.e. nothing selected. Maybe there's something wrong with the query?

Comment: seems so ... to prevent that, see my update.  But, yes, take a look at your query.

Comment: If you want it to return IVAN, you should be asking for the NAME in your query though and not the PLACE.

Comment: Tried it all ways around, still gives a null. maybe something's not right with the helper?

Comment: Try it with a raw query Cursor c = DB.rawQuery("SELECT NAME FROM PLACE WHERE PLACE = 'RUSSIA'");  See if that does the trick.

Comment: Even "Cursor c = DB.rawQuery("select * from MyTable", null);" gives a 0, so guess it more like something's with the helper... what do you think?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3452/discussion-between-roger-and-sberg413)

Answer (score 2):

> The Cursor object returned by a query provides access to a recordset
>   of results.

Once you have the Cursor, you have to iterate through it to get the values. In your case, you would do it like so --

```
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    int placeColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("PLACE"); 
    String place = cur.getString(placeColumn);
}
```

To get the NAME out based on a query by PLACE, you should do `PLACE = ?`

```
 Cursor c = DB.query(
            "MyTable" /* table */,
            new String[] { "NAME" } /* columns */,
            "PLACE = ?" /* where or selection */,
            new String[] { "RUSSIA" } /* selectionArgs */,
            null /* groupBy */,
            null /* having */,
            null /* orderBy */
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yet didn't really understand, how should I form the query? Maybe a little snippet, please. :)

Comment: Maybe it is possible to use "normal", i.e. in one string queries? Like the execSQL in the helper?

Comment: You want to get the "NAME" column based on PLACE = 'RUSSIA' .. I posted a DB.query. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. You could alternatively just replace the 'PLACE = ?' with "PLACE ='RUSSIA'" and then pass null as your fourth argument.

Comment: Thanks! Yes still it returns empty, i.e. c.getCount() = 0.